Program got stuck after compiled by TDM-gcc-64bits with -pg flag (used for gprof) on Windows
I am using gcc 10.3.0 from TDM-gcc-64bits on Windows platform, and I am trying the gprof tool. However, after passing the -pg argument to gcc, my program cannot terminate normally, instead, after it have done what I've written in the program (e.g. compute something, output something), it got stuck, the CPU occupancy rate seems to be zero for this program, and neither ctrl+c nor ctrl+z plus Enter can exit this program, I have to close the command console by mouse.
This happened for any codes on my PC, including a very time-comsuming program and even a simple helloworld program. It works fine with gcc under WSL. Is it a bug of TDM-gcc-64bits, or am I missing some arguments to the compiler? Many thanks!
